# Рихтер Совершенствование безопасности типов за счет явной реализации интерфейсных методов

Tags: c#, исключения, интерфейс, приведение-типов

Разбираю интерфейсы по рихтеру и возник впорос, на который не могу найти ответ

```
    public interface IComparable
{
    int CompareTo(object other);
}

internal struct SomeValueType : IComparable
{
    private int m_x;
    public SomeValueType(int x)
    {
        this.m_x = x;
    }
    public int CompareTo(object other)
    {
        return (m_x - ((SomeValueType)other).m_x);
    }
}
            SomeValueType v = new SomeValueType(0);
        Object o = new Object();
        Int32 n = v.CompareTo(v);
        n = v.CompareTo(o); // Исключение InvalidCastException Почему здесь возникает это исключение?
```

Comment: Вы понимаете, что эта строчка вообще делает?

Comment: Сравнивается объект v c o. 
Объект o должен приводиться к типу SomeValueType и я не понимаю почему возникает исключение, ведь object для всех типов является базовым и как я понимаю из любого типа можно получить object

Comment: "из любого типа можно получить object" - это правильно, но вы-то пытаетесь сделать наоборот, а вот это уже невозможно